# Spring SCALA return list in RestController

Tags: json, spring, scala, rest, serialization

How can I return a SCALA **list** or sequence in Sprint @RestController. List return value is **not being serialized** properly.

The result is:

```
[GET] http://localhost:9090/devices

{"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}
```

Do I need to import Jackson ObjectMapper `com.fasterxml.jackson` for proper REST get result serialization on a list?

My RestController looks like this:

```
@RestController
class DeviceController {

  var devices = Set[Device]()

  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/devices"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
  def accounts() : List[Device] =  devices.toList
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring was **NOT** designed with SCALA in mind - hence it **cannot** handle SCALA lists properly. Nor can it handle Seq[Device].

Just use SCALA's **JavaConvertes** package to easliy convert SCALA list to JAVA list.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

@RestController
class DeviceController {

  var devices = Set[Device]()

  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/devices"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
  def accounts() : java.util.List[Device] =  {
    devices.toList.asJava
  }
}
```

and the result will be:

```
[GET] http://localhost:9090/devices
[{"name":"first device"},{"name":"second device"}]
```

Remember to change the result type to:  `java.util.List[Device]`